# SQL insert resulting in null fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to input data from textboxes into a SQL database, and when I do, it is only inserting null fields.

here my code :

```
 sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Department (Description, Comments, Permissions, Active, Production) VALUES (@description, @comments, @permissions, @active, @production)", sqlConnection);

 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@comments", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@permissions", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Int);
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@production", SqlDbType.Int);

 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtDescription.Text);
 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtComments.Text);
 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@permissions", txtPermissions.Text);
 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt32(chkActif.Checked)));
 sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@production", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt32(chkProduction.Checked)));
 sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: use one or the other preferably use sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue() its better in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing some static values to your query.

Second thing try converting your `textbox.Text` `toString()`. Make sure you have `runat="server"` in the textbox tag and check you are not setting value to "" anywhere in your code.

Comment: Yup ! Many thanks ! Really helped me out for the job, I'm new in ASP and understanding why my fields was cleared on the pageload, helped me to understand the logic

Answer (score 7):

You are adding the Parameters twice!
Change your code to.

```
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Department (Description, Comments, Permissions, Active, Production) VALUES (@description, @comments, @permissions, @active, @production)", sqlConnection);

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", txtDescription.Text);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", txtComments.Text);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@permissions", txtPermissions.Text);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt32(chkActif.Checked)));
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@production", Convert.ToString(Convert.ToUInt32(chkProduction.Checked)));
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I've tryed without, still input nothing in the db

Comment: Create a breakpoint at the first parameter and see if the value is null?

Comment: @Brian yeah, the textboxes are null, why ?

Comment: Null or empty?  They are two different things.  If null then, yes, that is what is going to get written to the DB.

Comment: empty, why do they get empty when I click a button ?